# Add a delay of n seconds between playing videos in a directory

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I want to play all or few videos inside a directory. But I want to keep a delay of some seconds between playing two videos.

If I try something like

```sh
for video in $dir ; do
    $(sleep 10 && xdg-open $video) # or $(xdg-open $video && sleep 10)
done
```

Then the video only plays for 10 seconds and then the next video starts automatically.

I also tried to make a sleep of video duration + 10 seconds, but then suppose the user forwards or rewinds the video then this won't work.

How do I achieve a delay of 10 seconds between 2 videos playing?

This would be something like wait of a long process to complete, then add a delay of few seconds and then resume again.

Comment: The problem of your script is that the `xdg-open $video` command ends directly after launching the video (not at the end of the video).

Comment: What is the default video player `xdg-open` launches ? vlc ?

Comment: No, it is the "Videos" Application of Ubuntu

Comment: You may have to explicitly call your player (i.e. replace `xdg-open` by `totem`, `vlc`, ...) for it to work as intended. Here's a [Unix/linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/297932/find-the-default-application-for-a-certain-extension) stackexchange question showing how to determine your default softwares

Comment: @Aserre, I get the output for `xdg-mime query filetype video.mp4` as `video/mp4` The last part (after "/") changes with the file extension (e.g. for .avi it's `x-msvideo`)

Comment: Now try `xdg-mime query default video/mp4` to see the software used by xdg-open (or `xdg-mime query default x-msvideo`, though it should be the same output)

Comment: @Aserre I get the output as `org.gnome.Totem.desktop`.

Comment: @Aserre any idea on what to do next?